# How to replace String with unicode characters

Tags: java

I intend to replace strings with normal strings into split strings, but there is a difference in length between the normal strings which amounts to 62 and the split length turns out to be 117, so when we write the 'a' button it doesn't change to '' is there another way of writing replace string easier?

```
public static String doublestruck(String input){
    String normal = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String split = "ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ";

    String output = "";
    char letter;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        letter = input.charAt(i);
        int a = normal.indexOf(letter);
        output += (a != -1) ? split.charAt(a):letter;
    }
    return new StringBuilder(output).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The letters like  (U+1D7DC) are not in [the Basic Multilingual Pane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) and thus take up two `char` values in Java.

Instead of `charAt` you need to use [`codePointAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int)) and to find the correct offset you need to use [`offsetByCodePoint`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#offsetByCodePoints(int,int)) instead of directly using the same index. So `split.charAt(a)` needs to be replaced by `split.codePointAt(spli.offsetByCodePoint(0, a))`.

Comment: not into text, instead to letters, can you help me write the correct code? I guess the code was written wrong.